# order of constructor execution

Tags: c++, c++11

Does this code do what I would expect it to do? Meaning, is the handle_(curl_easy_init()) part called before or after constructor body execution?

```
class oauth2 {
public:
    oauth2() : handle_(curl_easy_init()) {
        if (handle_ == NULL) {
            throw new runtime_error("curl_easy_init return null");
        }
    }
    ~oauth2() {
        curl_easy_cleanup(handle_);
    }
private:
    CURL * handle_;
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Before. It's easy to check.

Comment: Quick way to find out is put something like `std::cout << typeid(this).name() << std::endl;` in each constructor (for complex types anyway). For primitive types you can use a lambda that returns a value of the appropriate type.

Comment: one point for using member/base initializer list instead of just putting everything into the constructor of the master object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is the handle_(curl_easy_init()) part called before or after
> constructor body execution?

It is called before execution of the constructor body.

---

C++ Standard n3337 **§** 12.6.2.10:

### Initializing bases and members

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the
> following order:
>
> — First, and only for the constructor of the most
> derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are initialized in the order
> they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed
> acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of
> appearance of the base classes in the derived class
> base-specifier-list.
>
> — Then, direct base classes are initialized in
> declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list
> (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
>
> — **Then, non-static
> data members are initialized** in the order they were declared in the
> class definition (again regardless of the order of the
> mem-initializers).
>
> — Finally, the compound-statement of the
> constructor body is executed.

The *delegating constructor* in this excerpt is defined as a constructor which calls another constructor of the same class (so it delegates the job). In such a case the former is called *principal constructor* while latter is called *target constructor*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Member objects are constructed before the containing object.

Comment: More correctly, member objects are constructed before constructor body statements are evaluated, both as part of the process of constructing the containing object.

Comment: there is no containing object before constructor returns